# Vector calculus word problem

Tags: calculus

> A mountain climbers oxygen mask is leaking. If the surface of the mountain is represented by $z=5-x^2-2y^2$ and the climber is at $(1/2,-1/2,17/4)$ in what direction should the climber turn to descend the most rapidly?

**My solution so far:**

$$F_x=-2x \quad   F_x(1/2,-1/2,17/4)=-1$$

$$F_y=-4y \quad   F_y(1/2,-1/2,17/4)=2 $$

$$F_z=0  \quad    F_z(1/2,-1/2,17/4)=0$$

So then the gradient vector would be

$$F(x)=\langle -2x,-4y,0\rangle$$

$$F(1/2,-1/2,17/4)=\langle -1,2,0\rangle $$

Not sure where to go from here to get the final answer

Comment: [Here's a "how to"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical formatting on this site.

Comment: Also, I've fixed this question for you. And you're welcome!

Comment: Awesome thanks I will use that for next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you already have the information to find the gradient with $(x,y)=(\frac12,-\frac12)$: $\nabla z=-2xi-4yj=-i+2j$
To ascend the most rapidly the climber should go in the direction of the gradient.
To descend the most rapidly the climber should turn in the direction $-\nabla z=i-2j$

Comment: Whay about the z component?

Comment: And is your answer enough to answer the question?

Comment: And ascend shouldn't it be descend?

Comment: $z$ is in fact the direction you are going, so you are just looking for the gradient of $z$. The answer will just be the direction in vector form, whatever form you want to use: $(i,-2j)$ or $(1,-2)$

Comment: ascend will be in the direction of the gradient, descend is opposite, so changing every signs

Comment: Okay so since 1 represents x and -2 represents y can we give a direction from those?

Comment: Yes basically. I would just go with $(i,-2j)$ if not felling so sure

Comment: Okay so in this problem the orignal pt(1/2,-1/2,17/4) the z component 17/4 doesn't mean anything

Comment: Yep you can totally ignore it. It means you are at this point on the mountain surface right now, your direction should be on this $z$ line but up or down

Comment: Up and down or right and left?

Comment: Shouldn't x be rigjt or left and y be up and down

Comment: @Sophia $(i,-2j)$ is not correct notation. Either write $(1,-2)$ or $i-2j$.